# Use Latent Semantic Analysis with sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to write a script where I will calculate the similarity of few documents. I want to do it by using LSA. I have found the following code and change it a bit. I has as an input 3 documents and then as output a 3x3 matrix with the similarity between them. I want to do the same similarity calculation but only with sklearn library. Is that possible?

```
from numpy import zeros
from scipy.linalg import svd
from math import log
from numpy import asarray, sum
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

titles = [doc1,doc2,doc3]
ignorechars = ''',:'!'''

class LSA(object):
    def __init__(self, stopwords, ignorechars):
        self.stopwords = stopwords.words('english')
        self.ignorechars = ignorechars
        self.wdict = {}
        self.dcount = 0        
    def parse(self, doc):
        words = doc.split();
        for w in words:
            w = w.lower()
            if w in self.stopwords:
                continue
            elif w in self.wdict:
                self.wdict[w].append(self.dcount)
            else:
                self.wdict[w] = [self.dcount]
        self.dcount += 1
    def build(self):
        self.keys = [k for k in self.wdict.keys() if len(self.wdict[k]) > 1]
        self.keys.sort()
        self.A = zeros([len(self.keys), self.dcount])
        for i, k in enumerate(self.keys):
            for d in self.wdict[k]:
                self.A[i,d] += 1
    def calc(self):
        self.U, self.S, self.Vt = svd(self.A)
        return -1*self.Vt

    def TFIDF(self):
        WordsPerDoc = sum(self.A, axis=0)        
        DocsPerWord = sum(asarray(self.A > 0, 'i'), axis=1)
        rows, cols = self.A.shape
        for i in range(rows):
            for j in range(cols):
                self.A[i,j] = (self.A[i,j] / WordsPerDoc[j]) * log(float(cols) / DocsPerWord[i])

mylsa = LSA(stopwords, ignorechars)
for t in titles:
    mylsa.parse(t)
mylsa.build()
a = mylsa.calc()
cosine_similarity(a)
```

**From @ogrisel's answer:**

I run the following code, but my mouth is still open :) When TFIDF has max 80% similarity on two documents with the same subject, this code give me 99.99%. That's why I think that it is something wrong :P

```
dataset = [doc1,doc2,doc3]
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.5,stop_words='english')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(dataset)
lsa = TruncatedSVD()
X = lsa.fit_transform(X)
X = Normalizer(copy=False).fit_transform(X)

cosine_similarity(X)
```

Comment: In the above, what is the value of X that you are considering as similarity measure?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [TruncatedSVD](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/decomposition.html#truncated-singular-value-decomposition-and-latent-semantic-analysis) transformer from sklearn 0.14+: you call it with `fit_transform` on your database of documents and then call the `transform` method (from the same `TruncatedSVD` method) on the query document and then can compute the cosine similarity of the transformed query documents with the transformed database with the function: `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity` and [numpy.argsort](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) the result to find the index of most similar document.

Note that under the hood, scikit-learn also uses NumPy but in a more efficient way than the snippet you gave (by using the [Randomized SVD](http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.4061) trick by Halko, Martinsson and Tropp).

Comment: `TruncatedSVD` has `n_components=2` by default. You probably need more, for instance `n_components=100`.

Comment: I've made few tests and everything above 2, gave the same result on 0.45. Instead of 0.77 of TFIDF. I will try to find a way to improve it, but your answer is the correct for this question. Thank you